# Where does ms-dos editor store settings?

Tags: windows-xp, text-editors

Where does ms-dos editor (edit) store settings in win xp?
Also, would these settings be easily transferrable to another OS, like win 7 or ms-dos?

I think it's edit.ini.

Comment: Just a note, it will not work on any 64-bit versions of windows, as it is a 64-bit executable.

Comment: @soandos you mean 16 bit?

Comment: @DanielBeck, ouch, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `edit.com` does indeed store its settings in `edit.ini` in the same path as the executable file. You can copy the settings to another OS by copying the `edit.ini` file to the same place as the target `edit.com` file (or just copy both to wherever you want).

The only caveat is that if you use a shortcut to run the program, make sure to set the starting directory to that of the executable so that it sees the `edit.ini` file in its current-working-directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to track where the file is based on process name.